# Zend 2 framework simple website routing

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework

I'm trying simple routing in zend for educational purposes. Before i say anything i downloaded 3 zend tutorials, 4 pdf's and I'm still stuck  on the simplest tasks. I even read the official documentation but still i can't understand how it works.

I'm trying to create simple bootstrap Home About and Contact page and found no luck in how routing works. I tried configuring module/ModuleName/module.config.php
adding custom routes but with no luck. Do i need to have for every static page like About and Contact seperate modules or one module and seperate controllers for each page? And how to handle routing www.example.com/about all i got is this and it's not working

**This is my module.config.php**

```
namespace Application;

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            'about' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/about',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\About',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

In src/Application/Controler i have IndexControler.php and AboutController.php
and in view/application/index index.phtml and about phtml.

**AboutController**

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http:/o/github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2015 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class AboutController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

}
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What error message do you get when you visit your about page URL?

Comment: error with the controller and route.

Comment: @L.Lawliet, Have you added you controllers files in controllers invokables array in module.config.php?

Comment: No i heaven't i don't even know what is it. Can you please elaborate that for me. 
And what is really confusing for me do i need different module for every page i make like about home and contact?
And when i read <?php echo $this->content; ?>  I heaven t found anywhere in class where it is defined content to be load on this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing invokables. In you above module.config.php file you should also add these below lines so that your code will start working.

Add this below code in module.config.php

```
'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Applcation\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
            'Applcation\Controller\About' => 'Application\Controller\AboutController',
            'Applcation\Controller\Contact' => 'Application\Controller\ContactController',
             ),
    ),
```

This link will give a better idea what is missing.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html

Good Luck